# Trying to track down a Scifi short story about a family trapped in a virtual museum exhibit

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a short Science fiction story I read in the 70's about a family trapped in a virtual museum exhibit where the day plays over and over again. The horror of their situation is that they start developing consciousness but are fated to keep repeating the day over and over until a car crashes into the exhibit and frees them.

Comment: Could it be "Not for an Age" by Brian Aldiss, as describd here? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/229927/sf-short-story-about-a-man-trapped-reliving-the-same-day-over-and-over/229928#229928